# How do Dynamic binding in PHP?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm trying to develop a little MVC Site in PHP to work with passwords. (Without any framework like Laravel or similar, for learning purposes).

In order to do so I've write at least 4 classes and an index file:

Controller -> A base class to be extended contaning all the basic logic for controllers;

Index -> A controller class to handle with normal user's login;

Admin -> A controller class to handle with admin users's login;

Bootstrap -> A class to interpret the url passed and use as a router;

The classes are shown as follow:

libs/Controller.php

```
<?php

class Controller {

    protected $view;
    protected $security_level;

    function __construct() {
        $this->security_level = 0;
    }

    public function model($model) {
        $path = 'models/' . ucfirst($model). '.php';
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            require_once ($path);
            return new $model();
        }   
    }

    public function getSecurityLevel(){
        return $this->securiy_level;
    }

    public function view($view, $data = []){
        require_once('views/commom/header.php');
        require_once('views/' . $view . '.php');
        require_once('views/commom/footer.php');
    }

}
```

controllers/Index.php

```
<?php

class Index extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->model('UserModel');
        //$this->securiy_level = 0;
    }

    public function index($error = 0) {
        $this->view('index/index', ['error' => $error]);
    }

    public function admin($error = 0) {
        $this->view('index/index_adm', ['error' => $error]);
    }

    public function login(){
        $auth = new Authentication();
        $permission = $auth->authenticate("user");
        if($permission){
            header("location: /account/index");
        }
        else{
            $this->index(1);
        }
    }

    public function login_adm(){
        $auth = new Authentication();
        $permission = $auth->authenticate("admin");
        if($permission){
            header("location: /admin/index");
        }
        else{
            $this->admin(1);
        }
    }

    public function signin(){
        echo "method sign in invoked <br />";
    }

    public function logout(){
        $this->view('index/logout');
    }

    public function lostMyPassword(){
        echo "method lost invoked <br />";  
    }

    public function details() {
        $this->view->view('index/index');
    }

}
```

controllers/Admin

```
<?php

//I Think that this is VERY wrong, but okay
@session_start();

class Admin extends Controller {

    private $encrypt_unit;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->model('UserModel');
        $this->encrypt_unit = new Encrypter();
        $this->securiy_level = 1;
    }

    public function index($msg = "", $err = false){
        $users = $this->recover();
        $this->view('admin/index', ["msg" => $msg, "err" => $err, "users" => $users]);
    }

    public function create(){
        $user_var = new UserModel();
        $user_var->setLogin($_POST["login"]);
        $user_var->setEmail($_POST["email"]);
        $user_var->setPassword($this->encrypt_unit->encrypt($_POST["password"]));
        $user_var->setIsAdmin($_POST["isAdmin"]);

        $user_dao = new UserDAO();
        $flag = $user_dao->insertUser($user_var);

        if($flag)
            $this->index("User created successfully", false);
        else
            $this->index("Can't created user, please try again", true);
    }

    public function recover(){
        $user_dao = new UserDAO();
        $all_users = $user_dao->getUsers();

        $users = array();
        foreach ($all_users as $value) {
            array_push($users, [
            "id" => $value->getId(),
            "login" => $value->getLogin(),
            "email" => $value->getEmail(),
            "password" => $this->encrypt_unit->decrypt($value->getPassword()),
            "isAdmin" => $value->getIsAdmin()
            ]);
        }

        return $users;
    }

    public function update(){
        $user_var = new UserModel();
        $user_var->setId($_POST["id"]);
        $user_var->setLogin($_POST["login"]);
        $user_var->setEmail($_POST["email"]);
        $user_var->setPassword($this->encrypt_unit->encrypt($_POST["password"]));

        $user_dao = new UserDAO();
        $flag = $user_dao->updateUser($user_var);

        if($flag)
            $this->index("User updated successfully", false);
        else
            $this->index("Can't updated user, please try again", true);
    }

    public function update_credential($credential_level){
        $user_var = new UserModel();
        $user_var->setId($_POST["id"]);
        $user_var->setIsAdmin($credential_level);

        $user_dao = new UserDAO();
        $flag = $user_dao->updateUserCredential($user_var);

        if($flag)
            $this->index("User updated successfully", false);
        else
            $this->index("Can't updated user, please try again", true);
    }

    public function delete(){
        $user_var = new UserModel();
        $user_var->setId($_POST["id"]);

        $user_dao = new UserDAO();
        $flag = $user_dao->deleteUser($user_var);

        if($flag)
            $this->index("User deleted successfully", false);
        else
            $this->index("Can't deleted user, please try again", true);
    }

    public function search(){
        echo "method search invoked <br />";
    }

}
```

libs/Bootstrap:

```
<?php

class Bootstrap {

    // protected $controller;
    // protected $method;
    // protected $params;

    function __construct() {
        //$this->method = 'index';
        $this->redirect();
    }

    public function parseUrl(){

        return isset($_GET['url']) ? explode('/',filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)) : null;
    }

    function redirect(){

        $controller;
        $method;
        $params;

        $url = $this->parseUrl();

        if(empty($url[0])){
            $controller_name = 'Index';
        }
        else{
            $controller_name = ucfirst($url[0]);
        }

        $filename_controller = 'controllers/' . $controller_name . '.php';

        if (file_exists($filename_controller)) {
            require_once($filename_controller);
            // Do this to use the rest of array to select method, and than parameters
            unset($url[0]);
        }
        else{
            $this->error("Controller $controller_name not founded");
            return false;
        }

        $controller = new $controller_name;

        //default method
        $method = 'index';

        if(isset($url[1])){
            if (method_exists($controller, $url[1])) {
                $method = $url[1];
                // Do this to use the rest of array to select parameters
                unset($url[1]);
            }
            else{
                $this->error("The controller $controller_name doesn't have any public method called $url[1]");
            }
        }

        //This 'array_values($url)' command is possible because we have unseted the first and second position of this aray before
        $params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

        // Securiy comparassion?
        var_dump($controller);
        var_dump(get_class_methods($controller));
        var_dump($controller->getSecurityLevel());
        var_dump($controller->{"getSecurityLevel"}());
        // if(property_exists($controller, "securiy_level")){
        //  $authEntity = new Authentication();
        //  $authEntity->auth($controller->getSecurityLevel());
        // }

        //(new $url[0])->{$url[1]}($url[2]);
        call_user_func_array([$controller, $method], $params);
    }

    function error($msg="") {
        //echo "error invoked: <br /> $msg <br />";
        require_once('controllers/Error.php');
        $errorHandler = new ErrorController();
        $errorHandler->index();
        return false;
    }

}
```

/index.php:

```
<?php

// Use an autoloader!
require_once('libs/Bootstrap.php');
require_once('libs/Controller.php');
require_once('libs/Model.php');
require_once('libs/View.php');

// Library
require_once('libs/Database.php');
require_once('libs/ConnectionDB.php');
require_once('libs/Session.php');
require_once('libs/Authentication.php');
require_once('libs/Encrypter.php');

require_once('config/paths.php');
require_once('config/database.php');
require_once('config/passwords.php');

// DAOS
require_once('daos/UserDAO.php');
require_once('daos/AccountDAO.php');


$app = new Bootstrap();
```

My main problem is on the Bootstrap class, specifically when I try to run:

```
var_dump($controller->getSecurityLevel()); //or
var_dump($controller->{"getSecurityLevel"}());
```

This is my actual exit, when I try to access the page "http://localhost/index/" is:

> object(Index)#2 (2) { ["view":protected]=> NULL
>   ["security_level":protected]=> int(0) }
>
> array(12) { [0]=> string(11) "__construct" [1]=> string(5) "index"
>   [2]=> string(5) "admin" [3]=> string(5) "login" [4]=> string(9)
>   "login_adm" [5]=> string(6) "signin" [6]=> string(6) "logout" [7]=>
>   string(14) "lostMyPassword" [8]=> string(7) "details" [9]=> string(5)
>   "model" [10]=> string(16) "getSecurityLevel" [11]=> string(4) "view" }
>
> ** Notice: Undefined property: Index::$securiy_level in /var/www/html/libs/Controller.php on line 21 ** NULL
>
> ** Notice: Undefined property: Index::$securiy_level in /var/www/html/libs/Controller.php on line 21 ** NULL

What I cannot understand is how PHP shows me that the `$controller` variable has the property that I want to access, I have the method to do the access, but I cannot access. And what does means the "static" bind that PHP is trying to do when he shows: "Index::$securiy_level".

I know about scope in PHP (at least a little bit).
And what I'm intend to do using a variable "$security_level" in Controller class is to provide a default value to all controllers-child. If the programmer do not want to explicit declare a different value of $security_level,he/she do not be worried about it, just use the father's property.

My configuration is: PHP 7, Ubuntu 16, apache2;

Any help I will thank in advanced.

If my question is not clear, please comment it too to clarify anything.

*Obs.: Please notice the output when I try to access "http://localhost/admin" is:

> object(Admin)#2 (4) { ["encrypt_unit":"Admin":private]=> 
>   object(Encrypter)#3 (2) { ["encrypt_key":"Encrypter":private]=>
>   string(20) "RmUzYm1hcUxnY3ZYcA=="
>   ["encrypt_algorithm":"Encrypter":private]=> string(11) "aes-256-cbc" }
>   ["view":protected]=> NULL ["security_level":protected]=> int(0)
>   ["securiy_level"]=> int(1) }
>
> array(11) { [0]=> string(11) "__construct" [1]=> string(5) "index"
>   [2]=> string(6) "create" [3]=> string(7) "recover" [4]=> string(6)
>   "update" [5]=> string(17) "update_credential" [6]=> string(6) "delete"
>   [7]=> string(6) "search" [8]=> string(5) "model" [9]=> string(16)
>   "getSecurityLevel" [10]=> string(4) "view" } int(1) int(1)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I highly doubt anyone is going to read through all that.  Please try to narrow down your issue to something specific and make sure that the included code is _relevant_ to that specific problem.

Comment: That's a huge wall of code for people to try and go through. Please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can look at for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in Controller, `return $this->securiy_level;` should be `return $this->security_level;` ;)

Comment: OMG I'dont believe this so stupid mistake was causing so much confusing for me.!!!
Thanks a lot @Rarst.

Comment: @Rarst typos should be closed with the appropriate reason (under off-topic), along with a comment.

Comment: @PatrickQ gotcha, I am not very familiar with SO close reasons, didn't know about that one :)